# Any mail vs Any mails

Tags: grammar, uncountable-nouns

I wonder why do we say

> **Is there any mail for me?**

rather than

> **Is there any mails for me?**

As far as I know, whenever the word **any** is used, we have to add an *s* to the end of the next word.

Comment: Whenever the word **any** is used, it's part of a *plural* noun phrase, so it would be ***Are** there any emails for me?* OR the relevant noun is "uncountable" (which is possible with both ***email*** and ***mail***, but note that only ***emails*** are normally countable, not ***mails***).

Comment: RE: _we have to add an s to the end of the next word_ – that is grossly oversimplified. Try thinking of it this way: "When you use the word _any_, the **noun it modifies** should be in its **plural form**." (1) For some words, that's the same as the singular form. _Have you seen any deer? Have you caught any fish? Have you eaten any rice? Did you drink any water?_ (2) The way you've written your "rule" (you said, "the next word") you don't account for possible adjectives:  _Did you buy any live worms? Does she have any sharp arrows? Are you selling any big trucks?_